# How does topic or tag suggestion algorithms work?

Tags: algorithms, strings, semantics, search

I know it's a keyword based search. But sites like Quora have some good suggesting algorithms where the algorithm understands the intent of question asked rather than just the keywords meanings.

For instance, for a question involving "O(n^2)" it adds 'Algorithms' and 'Computer Science' as topics and for a question involving "limit on friends in Facebook" it adds 'Facebook friends' as a topic. So it's more of a semantic search.

Google search also works on the same principles of semantic search. So how exactly does tag suggestion algorithm work?

Comment: Can you make your question self contained by explaining what is topic suggestion algorithm..

Answer (score 1):

Read about [topic modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) in natural language processing.  There are many techniques; e.g., [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) is one simple standard approach.